# Cross Browser Html Table Help Design Php

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how to improve an html table which is too wide. For example i have td's for each supervisors (7 in total and each one represented by a pic) and each supervisor has 35 workers, which is on the next tr (inside such tr i make a table) corresponding their own supervisor. Each tr shows the workers for that supervisor and the number of products he/she sold out (prod1, prod2, prod3 each prod on a different column). This make a table really wide and i need a way to improve it as well. Can anyone gimme an idea?
Id also like to know how can make a cross browser css so that this could be seen on a 42inches LCD TV and on a normal monitor device.

This is an example of what I've done so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/byv79g6u/

```
<table align='center' border='1'>
<tr>
    <th colspan='6' height='205'><img src='' alt='Here goes 1th Sup. Img'></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>prod1</th>
    <th>prod2</th>
    <th>prod3</th>
    <th>prod4</th>
    <th>prod5</th>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>username1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>username2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>username3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>username30</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I repeat that pattern for each supervisor I have (minimum 7)

Comment: It sounds like a layout design and not a technical problem. Show us what you want to achieve and what you've tried so far and then we can help.

Comment: I have a single mock up but when i try to attach it i cant because i dont have a 10 reputation. what i've done is insider a table my first tr, then i make a th (or a td) inside it, i add a pic (showing a supervisor) on the next tr, i make some heading like: username, prod1, prod2, prod3. On the next tr i show the usernames belonging to this supervisor with the amount of products he/she (users) sold out. I repeat this step as many supervisors i had (on fly with php). my table gets really wide and i need some idea to make it look fancy even for monitor and a LCD TV 42inch.

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net and create an example of your code, then add a link in the question's body

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/byv79g6u/ This is what ive done, and i need to repeat that pattern as many supervisors i had (6 as minimum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each table inside a div and set `float: left`

See the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/byv79g6u/1/)

Comment: I need to show this wide table on a lcd 42 inches and it should wotk for cpu monitors. Maybe you have another way to show it